# Recordset.MoveNext very strange behavior. Why?

Tags: ms-access

Microsoft Access 2010, DAO.Recordset

I found a very strange behavior in the .move method. Does anyone know why this happens?

At first the recordset is loaded

```
Dim rc as DAO.Recordset
Set rc = CurrentDB.Openrecordset(" ... ")
Debug.Print rc.RecordCount  ' 1273
```

And now, this works:

```
rc.MoveFirst
rc.Move 500
```

This does NOT work:(WHY???)

```
rc.MoveFirst
rc.Move 1272
```

And now it gets strange: This works again...

```
rc.MoveFirst
rc.Move 1272
if rc.AbsolutePosition = -1 then
  rc.MoveFirst
  rc.Move 1272
end if
```

Comment: when you say it "does not work", are you getting an error or is it doing something other than what you expected? If the latter, what are you expecting it to do?

Comment: In addition to answering attila's questions, it may help to give us some details about what you're asking `OpenRecordset()` to open.

Comment: rc.AbsolutePosition gets -1, so no record is selected and rc![ID] is empty (and throws an error). 

`OpenRecordset("QueryName")` and `OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM [Tablename]") does the same`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before your first `mc.MoveFirst`, try adding `mc.MoveLast`.  This would force the recordset to populate.  My guess would be that the recordset hasn't fully populated when you try to move to the last record.